# Attempting to do a fetch DELETE but keep getting syntax error: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest

I am attempting to do a fetch DELETE request from my client React app and am getting the following error when I try to delete a note from my app:

> error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

I get this error in the console and I can still see the note however, if I refresh the page the note is gone. How can I fix this?

```
handleClickDelete = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const noteId = this.props.id;

  fetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/notes/${noteId}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json"
      }
    })
    .then(res => {
      if (!res.ok) return res.json().then(error =>
        Promise.reject(error));
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(() => {
      this.context.removeNote(noteId);
      this.props.onDeleteNote(noteId);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error({
        error
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: Could you please provide server response.

Comment: I receive a successful 204 response. I however throw the {error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input}  in the console

Comment: It seems you got an empty body in response.

Answer (score 1):

@Laxmikant is right. You should have an empty body and in your response and in your callback you are trying to parse your response to a JSON: `res.json()`